# Converting Eclipse dynamic web project to maven project with modules

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, servlets

so I just started a new project at work where I've gotten some code, really strange code...

So the project structure was as follows:

simple-java-project-1 ---> eclipse java project which holds some database-connectors

simple-java-project-2 ---> holds the logic of converting, formatting etc of the data, uses the connectors from project-1

dynamic-web-project --> just gets the jars from project1 and project2 and offer's a websocket api to send this data etc.

---

I would like to convert this mess to a well structured maven project. So I created a master maven project with this pom:

```
    ......bla bla bla....
    <modules>
        <module>the-connectors</module>
        <module>the-logic</module>
        <module>the-dynamic-web-module</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencies>.....</dependencies/>
```

And the modules as well. I added the dependencies needed to them.

So now the hard part I didn't get : How can I achive that the whole project is deployed to the local tomcat and runs?

The web.xml and /WEB-INF/ stuff is in the "the-dynamic-web-module" module for now,...

Any ideas or hints?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the tomcat7-maven-plugin to your `the-dynamic-web-module`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
                <uriEncoding>UTF-8</uriEncoding>
                <systemProperties>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

After building and installing the 2 other modules (`mvn install`), go to `the-dynamic-web-module` and launch `mvn tomcat7:run`. Then with your browser, go to `localhost:8080/` and you should get your app.

Comment: and is there anything i have to configure about the web.xml file ? or the referenced servlet from the web.xml? (I'm at home now, i will try more tomorrow)

Comment: I run my web apps like that with an empty web.xml. So I guess you just use the conf needed by your webapp and the plugin runs it.